# Cannot read parquet file metadata for each field with the arrow package for R

Tags: r, metadata, parquet, apache-arrow

I am trying to read metadata for each field of a parquet file hosted in a S3 bucket using `arrow` for `R`. I am able to load the parquet file into `R` without issue, but I only get `NULL` as response when trying to access the metadata for each field in the parquet file.

I know there is metadata included for each field because I am able to access this information if I use `pyarrow`. I am developing scripts in `R` to show people how to access these files easily, so the solution must be using `R` libraries, it does not have to be `arrow` specifically.

I am reading a parquet file from a S3 bucket using the `arrow` package for `R` using the following code:

```
library(arrow)

#Establishing connection
data_bucket <- s3_bucket("s3://rimrep-data-public/abs-regional-lga-2021/data.parquet")

#Accessing ABS dataset
data_df <- open_dataset(data_bucket)
```

This opens the file exactly as I would expect. But when I try to access the metadata with either: `data_df$schema$metadata` or `data_df$metadata`, I only get the name of the field and the type of data contained in that column. A shorten version of the output looks like this:

```
$pandas
[1] "{\"index_columns\": [\"fid\"], \"column_indexes\": [{\"name\": null, \"field_name\": null, \"pandas_type\": \"unicode\", \"numpy_type\": \"object\", \"metadata\": {\"encoding\": \"UTF-8\"}}], \"columns\": [{\"name\": \"DATAFLOW\", \"field_name\": \"DATAFLOW\", \"pandas_type\": \"unicode\", \"numpy_type\": \"object\", \"metadata\": null},...}
```

This output looks exactly like the result I get if I use the `pyarrow` package.

If I then try to get metadata for one field using either: `data_df$schema$DATAFLOW$metadata` or `data_df$schema[1]$DATAFLOW$metadata`, I get `NULL` as a result. If use `data_df$schema[1]$metadata` I get `named list()` as a result.

However, if I use the `pyarrow` package to get metadata for a single field using
`md.schema[0].metadata`, I will get a different result, which includes a description of the field, the units and multiplier used (if applicable). This looks something like this:

```
{b'Description': b'Persons who have need for assistance with....',
 b'units': b'Percent',
 b'multiplier': b'None'}
```

**My question is how can I get the same metadata output for a single field using `arrow` for `R` as I do with the `pyarrow` package?** I tried using `$metadata$r` as suggested in their [documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/reference/Schema-class.html?q=metad#r-metadata), but I still get `NULL` as a result.

Comment: While I don't know _why_, that link you presented does say *"Pandas has its own custom metadata"*. From this and the fact that the metadata accessed by R uses the similarly language-specific `$metadata$r` suggests that the two do not overlap. In order to have shared metadata, my guess is you'd need to put in a FR ... and a non-trivial one at that, as it will either break backwards compatibility (unlikely), double the metadata attributes, or reverse what seems like a deliberate decision to keep them separate.